# SQL injection with filtered column names

Tags: sql-injection

I have the following MySQL query susceptible to an injection and I need to extract the password of a given user:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' and password='$password'
```

However from the injection, I can see that before the request is posted, the fields `$login` and `$password` are filtered. In particular, the PHP scripts detects "OR" being used in the following injection:

```
login => ' || ''='
password => ' || login='bobby' && passwORd LIKE 'A%'
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='' || ''='' && password='' || login='bobby' && passwORd LIKE 'A%''
```

The "OR" appearing in `$password` is detected, and the injection fails.

Is there any known way to bypass this?

Comment: Not sure why you need to inject the password along with the user name.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to inject into the `$password` variable. Just [comment out](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html) the rest of the query with the `$login` variable. Setting `$login` to `bobby' --` will give you this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='bobby' -- ' and password='foobar'
```

Comment: Or wait... Do you want to exfiltrate the password by testing it letter by letter? Then this is not the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. One can use another SELECT as a password. It is very error prone to use filtering.

Use **prepared statement** instead. Then you don't care at all of what user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

#### Exploit

You can comment out the `$password` variable as anders said.

If you want to find out the passwords use [sqlmap](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap) to dump the database. Doing this manual takes much time.

#### Fix

To fix the SQL-Injection simply use a prepared statement.

The second weakness is, that the passwords are stored in plain text. You should store them as a hash of the password.